# Dialog gets closed on ajax calls

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, modal-dialog

I'm having using Primefaces. I have a dataTable inside dialog and when I try to sort/filter it, the dialog closes.I assume that whenever an ajax call is made it closes the dialog. I also tried to make a "test" sample button and it also closes the dialog. **Is there a way to prevent this?**

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" deferredMode="true" deferred="visible">
    <p:dialog height="700px" width="100%" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true" header="Sample table" widgetVar="sampleDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">   
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable    id="fooTableCurrent" 
                            var="business" 
                            value="#{mainViewController.lazyModel}"
                            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                            paginator="true" rows="20" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"
                            rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100,200"
                            emptyMessage="No records found with given criteria"
                            editable="true"
                            lazy="true"
                            scrollable="true"
                            scrollHeight="100px">


                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{mainViewController.onBusinessRowEdit}"  />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{mainViewController.onBusinessRowCancel}" />

                <p:column headerText="Employee reg. #">
                    <h:outputText value="#{business.employee.employee_ID}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Employee">
                    <h:outputText value="#{business.employee.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Bank">
                    <h:outputText value="#{business.bank.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Office" filterStyle="width:60px;" filterBy="#{business.office.office_ID}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <h:outputText value="#{business.office.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Product group" style="width: 100px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{business.product.product_group.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Product" filterStyle="width:60px;" filterBy="#{business.product.product_ID}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{business.product.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Contract" filterStyle="width:60px;" filterBy="#{business.contract}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{business.contract}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Value" sortBy="#{business.value}">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{business.value}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><h:inputText value="#{business.value}" /></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Date" sortBy="#{business.insert_date}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{business.insert_date}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Approved" width="55" style="text-align: center;">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="true" value="#{true}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column style="width:32px" headerText="Edit">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Delete" width="30">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{mainViewController.deleteBusiness(business)}" update="@form">
                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                    </p:confirmDialog>

                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: This code is very noisy. Does the problem disappear when you remove the column "Employee"? No? Please omit it from your code snippet. Does the problem disappear when you remove `paginatorTemplate`? No? Please omit it from your code snippet. Does the problem disappear when you remove `scrollable="true"`? No? Please omit it from your code snippet. Carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and fix your question accordingly. By the way, my best guess would be a nested form.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in outputPanel tag. After removing `autoUpdate="true"`everything was working as a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see you added this to the question now, next time please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `oncomplete = 'PF.show('WIDGET_VAR_NAME)'` to force the dialog to show again.

Comment: That is kind of a workaround (compensating) while the other answer fixes (removes) the cause.

Comment: In my case, I retrieved the problem without any `autoUpdate="true"`. I posted my solution because it works for me.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification, but If you had the problem without `autoUpdate="true"` (and explicitly updated something outside the dialog) then you in fact had a different 'problem' with the same manifestation